# Automatic calculation of p-value in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, p-value

I'm a new user in ggplot2. I'm proceeding to calculate if there are significant difference among laboratories values after a treatment. I used R 
 Wilcoxon signed ranks test and I found a p-value < 0.05. I need to transform the results in graphs with boxplot, showing asterisk for the p-value. Is there an automatic way to show them?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please share a reproducible example with us: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and show us any attempt of code you try. (box plot, etc..)

Comment: Thanks Antonino. If you can show you what the boxplot contains it may be easier to help you. Please see this web example for inbuilt data sets (eg immer) that all R users have access to - http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/non-parametric-methods/wilcoxon-signed-rank-test. This as @timat suggests will help people help you

Comment: Hello, if you're looking for quick workaround you could save the results of your analysis into a separate data.frame. You could then use geom_text to plot the asterisks alongside the boxplots. This should also allow you to control where the asterisks occur as geom_text takes x and y values. Your new data.frame would need the x, y, and number of asterisks